# Fetch gender and Dob from google or Facebook SignIn

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-signin, google-people-api

I am working on Facebook and Google SignIn in my Project. I am fetching user information like gender, location and DOB. Only Issue I am facing is that for some user i am able to fetch the information and for others not getting gender and DOB.

Can anybody please let me that even if i am passing the required scope for gender and birthday while generating the accesstoken, is it still required the user to make the dob and gender info shared/public or it's not mandatory ?

Thanks,

Comment: Just because you pass the permissions in the scope, does not mean the user has to grant them. Plus, `gender` you will only get returned if the user has it set to either male or female (or if left blank, if it can be determined from their pronoun), for everyone who chooses any other value, you won’t get it at all.

Comment: @misorude will i get the gender if i haven't share it in my google account setting. Birthdate I have not shared, stilll i am able to fetch it.But In case of gender I am not able to do so

Comment: Sorry, my comment was mainly regarding Facebook.